# Importing an Android Library into Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

A third party provides an Android SDK which can be imported into Android Studio. Their SDK is not listed in Xamarin components section.

1. Can we import their Android SDK into Xamarin studio?
2. I found [an article about binding a Java library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/), is this an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SDK contains a JAR file, then yes follow the Xamarin documentation about importing the JAR into a binding project and wire up any configuration - such as method/member renames or exclusions etc.

See here for further guidance:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/